# How can I add a negative angle to a gradient?

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, angle, linear-gradients

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="-85"
        android:centerColor="@color/turquoise_action_bar"
        android:endColor="@color/dark_turquoise"
        android:startColor="@color/dark_turquoise" /> 
</shape>
```

In this code, I've given -85 as angle as per my photoshop design but people say that only it's ok with 180, 90 & 0 degrees, is there a way for -85 to be done for linear gradient.

Comment: You can not use -85 angle. Please post gradient image what actual you want to achieve.

Comment: Is there no way in android to provide angles other than 180, 90 & 0 degrees @AndyDeveloper If iam using a image may it vary to screens right? so which size will be better at all devices?

Thanks for quick response!

Comment: I think you need to create 9 patch image which fit all the devices and you never face the issue with size.Better try to 9 patch image.

Comment: I need a gradient of -100 degree in photoshop to be used in same way in android app

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2zVLPsWhkWLMlpFeTF5dS1aMVk

attached image link